# How to get the height of the Navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am developing my first iPhone application. I am quite new to iOS. I am trying to get the height of the UI Navigation bar using the code below below the `viewDidLoad` method

```
float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
```

But the navBarHeight is returning 0. Not sure why that is.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get height of navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312059/programmatically-get-height-of-navigation-bar)

Comment: If you are on iOS 6 or later (i.e. systems that support Auto Layout) you could try `[navigationBar intrinsicContentSize].height`.

Comment: Where are you calling your code? Is `self` in a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: That could be it. Self is in UIView I think rather than a UINavigation Controller. I need to check again when I get back to my station.

Comment: It might be custom UIView instead of UINavigationController.Some where else your hiding navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Might be your using custom UIView for navigation or your hiding NavigationBar in your code i.e.,why it showing height is 0.If you set below code in your viewWillAppear you will get height of NavigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension (considering iPhone-X)

```
extension UIViewController {

    /**
     *  Height of status bar + navigation bar (if navigation bar exist)
     */

    var topbarHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
print(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)
```