# How to access NavigationController's navigation bar size from my View in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I'm doing everything programmatically, and have no Storyboards. I'm using Swift2.0 and I'm a beginner. My app structure is very simple:

In my AppDelegate, I am initializing a `UINavigationController` and a ViewController, and adding my ViewController to my navigationController.

In my ViewController, `loadView()` method, I initialize my view: `self.view = myView()`

And so now I'm in myView class, where I'm trying to build my view (making 4 buttons, adding constraints). Now when I want to make my buttons, I need to know the navigationController's navigationBar size (height).

How can I access this from my View class? What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: "And so now I am in myView class" Where exactly? What method are you in? This makes a huge difference as to what you can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically get height of navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312059/programmatically-get-height-of-navigation-bar)

Comment: Right now, in my init method, I am calling a method that does all the layout for the view (adds all the buttons and constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want exact height of top bar (both navigation bar + status bar):

**Objective-C**

```
CGFloat topbarHeight = ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height +
       (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?: 0.0));
```

**Swift 4**

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
        (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
```

For ease, try this UIViewController extension

```
extension UIViewController {

    /**
     *  Height of status bar + navigation bar (if navigation bar exist)
     */

    var topbarHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height +
(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
```