# How can I center the view on the superview? swift

Tags: swift, swift3

This is my code

```
let view1 = UIView()
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(view1)
view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
view1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
view1.centerYAnchor.constraint((equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true)
```

The centerXAnchor of view1 is the same as the center of the Screen.
However cneterYAnchor is not same.

I use NavigationBar, I think centerYAnchor of view1 shift by height of the NavigationBar.

So, if `equalTo: superview.centerYAnchor` is possible, I can center the view.

Do you have any good ideas? I'm sorry I'm not good at English,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below

`view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -navBarHeight).isActive = true`

[Refere here for getting nav bar height programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312059/programmatically-get-height-of-navigation-bar)

If your requirement is as simple as centering the subview inside a view controller (which has navigation bar)

You can use the `view1.center` solution as well like below

`view1.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
view1.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width  / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Another option:

```
view1.center = self.view.convert(self.view.center, from:self.view.superview)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center vertically without the navigation bar affecting the constraint use the [safeAreaLayoutGuide](http://safeAreaLayoutGuide) `centerYAnchor`:

```
view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```